# How to create colour box with fixed width and height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am trying to create a color box with fixed width and height in a flutter.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Wrap any widget in a [`SizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) to force it to match a fixed size.

As for background colors or border, use [`DecoratedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html).

You can then combine both, which leads to

```
const SizedBox(
  width: 42.0,
  height: 42.0,
  child: const DecoratedBox(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red
    ),
  ),
),
```

You may as well use [`Container`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) which is a composition of many widgets including those two from above. Which leads to :

```
new Container(
  height: 42.0,
  width: 42.0,
  color: Colors.red,
)
```

I tend to prefer the first option. Because `Container` prevents the use of 'const' constructor. But both works and do the same.

Comment: Not working..., it always takes the height and width of screen

Comment: Linter 2 hints to avoid the use of `const`.

Comment: instead of SizedBox with height and width with the same value, we can use SizedBox.square and use only a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
FractionalTranslation(
    translation: Offset(0, 0),
        child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: SizedBox(
            height:  1,
            width: 1,
            child: const ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
        )
    ),
),
```